# Errors when the quantity is an exponent

Tags: homework-and-exercises, error-analysis, statistics

Errors add up in addition or subtraction.
Relative errors add up in multiplication or division.
When a quantity is raised to a power, the error is increased by times of the exponent.

---

Now what if the quantity itself is an exponent? What is the rule?

1. $\Delta A=\Delta a\pm\Delta b$ for $A=a+b$ or $A=a-b$
2. $\frac{\Delta A}{A}=\frac{\Delta a}{a} + \frac{\Delta b}{b}$ for $A=ab$ or $A=\frac{a}{b}$.
3. $\frac{\Delta A}{A}=\frac{m\Delta a}{a}+\frac{n\Delta b}{b}$ for $A=a^mb^n$ or $A=\frac{a^m}{b^n}$.

What if $A=e^{ab}$?

Comment: Scroll down as necessary: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The most general rule for uncertainty propagation comes from a derivative of the function.  If you sketch a graph of a function, you can see how this works.  For a function $f(x)$, if $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ is large, there is a steep slope, so a small change in $x$ results in a bigger change in $f$.
If $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ is small, there is a shallow slope, and a large change in $x$ could result in a small change in $f$.

The general rule is:
$$\Delta f(x,y,...) = \left|\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right| \Delta x + \left|\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right| \Delta y + ...$$

You can check that this reproduces your two rules.

This assumes that the variables $x$ and $y$ are **independent** and that we are using a definition where the **uncertainties add directly**, not in quadrature, as would be the case if the uncertainties were defined as the standard deviation of many measurements.

You can now apply this rule to your case: $A = e^{a b}$:

$$\Delta A = \left|\frac{\partial e^{a b}}{\partial a}\right| \Delta a + \left|\frac{\partial e^{a b}}{\partial b}\right| \Delta b = ... $$

I'll leave that for you to work out on your own.

Comment: So differentiate and get the relative errors! Got it.

Comment: There errors are added in quadrature. If they are correlated, you need to take that into account.

Answer (score 1):

There is a general rule that tells you how to compute errors of a function f (or A in your case). Have a look at this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty#Simplification) article. It tells that the error of a function $f$ is

$\Delta f(a,b,...) = \sqrt{(\frac{\partial f}{\partial a}\Delta a)^2 + (\frac{\partial f}{\partial b}\Delta b)^2}$

First, we see that your statements are not quite correct.

$f = a +b  \rightarrow \Delta f = \sqrt{\Delta a^2 + \Delta b^2}$

$f = a \cdot b  \rightarrow \Delta f = \sqrt{(\Delta a \cdot b)^2 + (\Delta b \cdot a)^2}$

For your question you see that for $f=e^{ab}$

$\Delta f  = \sqrt{(be^{ab}\cdot\Delta a)^2+(ae^{ab}\cdot\Delta b)^2}$

Comment: I disagree. As for my level (12th year in India) the formulae given in the question are only mentioned as we don't learn partial differentiation at school level

Comment: This uses the standard deviation definition of uncertainty, which is not the definition being used in the question.

Comment: My actual question was different actually, this was just a generalisation needed for that question...
So basically the std. deviation definition would suffice for my level.